# Use image to make circuit board

Tags: mesh, displacement

I'm trying to give a mesh a Circuit board texture with an image as the refrence.

[image: refrence]

I need the green lines to extrude out of a mesh. Here's my setup

[image: setup]

and here's what i got:

[image]

As you can see, the lines are fuzzy and distorted. how can I get them crisp and extruded?

Answer (score 5):

I think the displacement map not working properly is a side effect of the colour in the image. You probably want to convert that into grayscale before using it as a displacement map.

Well, with a quick bit of photoshop work, here's what I came up with. It's not perfect and you can see the pixels if you zoom in a bit too much, but it works somewhat.

Displacement map:
[image]

Colour:
[image]

Node Setup:
[image]

Final Result:
[image]

**Edit:**

Typically you won't want to plug in the normal map node. I did that because there were some shading issues that cropped up in Eevee, and it seemed to fix it. In cycles, it works fine without the Normal Map node.

[image]

Comment: Hello, some genuine questions :). Why not connect the BW image directly into the *Height* input on the *Displacement node*? And does the BW image have enough information to be used as a Normal map at all? I'm just curious :).

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Displacement maps probably weren't meant to be pure black/white. The displacement map was shading some areas black for some reason so I just threw in the normal map and it seemed to fix it. There's probably a better way to "rescale" the image (aside from directly editing the image). Then again...maybe its just something to do with Eevee because it works fine without the normal map in Cycles.

Comment: Thanks, always learning :).

Comment: True (generated-geometry) render-time displacement doesn't work with EEVEE at all. It's Cycles only, and still needs the Experimental feature-set to be switched on in my 2.81.

Comment: @RobinBetts good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Apologies to @stphnl329 for a very similar answer, but I got this far, and maybe there are a couple of extra points here...

[image]

- If the pattern on the reference image encodes anything, it encodes
  height, not normals.
- Agreed with @stphnl329, it's good to make a clean extraction of the green pixels as a black and white mask. (@stphnl's is better than mine)
- It's a toss-up: you might be able to give yourself more wriggle-room by blurring the mask. This will enable you to make variable selections/manipulations of the mask for use in the material itself. In the tree below, it enables the Color Ramp to determine the extent of the gold material, and the RGB Curve node to put a profile on the displacement.
- To avoid compression artifacts, and keep everything linear, strictly, you should save the mask as a floating-point .EXR. It may make no difference for what you want.

[image]

With the material's Settings > 'Displacement' set to 'Bump Only':

[image]

and with Displacement:

[image]

Maybe Displacement is overkill?

.... and when it comes down to it, I think I prefer @stphnl's render .... :D

Comment: There's much to be learned from yours, having the ability to edit the displacement sharpness in Blender with the nodes would definitely come in handy

Comment: @stphnl329 thanks for your generosity... anxious not to tread on your toes.. :)

Comment: No worries, I've got much to learn when it comes to nodes and texturing still :-)

Comment: FWIW, I prefer yours

Comment: For future reference - there's a lot of open-source hardware projects nowadays and a free tool called [gerbv](http://gerbv.geda-project.org/) which can export manufacturing files as SVGs. CADs themselves usually support DXF and sometimes STEP exports.

Comment: Or there are [PDFs ready sometimes](https://github.com/beagleboard/BeagleBoneEnhanced/blob/master/SanCloud_BeagleBone_Enhanced_1E_Final%20Artwork%20Prints.PDF).